# fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory ESP32 CAM

Tags: arduino-esp32

`Alternatives for bits/c++config.h: [] ResolveLibrary(bits/c++config.h) -> candidates: [] In file included from c:\users\dell\onedrive - national university of sciences & technology\documents\arduinodata\packages\esp32\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc\1.22.0-97-gc752ad5-5.2.0\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\5.2.0\algorithm:60:0, from C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive - National University of Sciences & Technology\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.6\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:142, from C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_678598\sketch\sketch_sep30a.ino.cpp:1: c:\users\dell\onedrive - national university of sciences & technology\documents\arduinodata\packages\esp32\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc\1.22.0-97-gc752ad5-5.2.0\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\5.2.0\utility:68:28:`
**fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory**

```
compilation terminated.
exit status 1
Error compiling for board AI Thinker ESP32-CAM.
```

Comment: The error message is very clean and loud, if you need help, you need to do more than just posting an error msg by explaining the problem you are facing. For example, do you have the said file, where it is located?

Comment: The file is missing but I couldn't find the file anywhere on the internet.

Comment: Does it works before with an ESP32? The error has to do with your gcc compiler and looks like you had a quite old esp32-arduino core (1.0.6) installed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved, and it was the large name of the folder in the directory that caused the error. As the name of the folder was made short the error vanished.

Comment: This is getting downvoted, but it's a [known bug](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/get-started/windows-setup.html): "Limitations: - The installation path of ESP-IDF and ESP-IDF Tools must not be longer than 90 characters. Too long installation paths might result in a failed build."